VLC show framerate of a video
When playing a video in vlc, and opening...
Tools > Codec Information
...I do not see the FPS listed. How can I check the FPS of the video using VLC?
Video was captured with org.gnome.Shell.Screencast

I expected the framerate to be included in the codec info.

ffprobe input.mp4
